# Splitting a 10amp 2.1mm DC barrel into positive and negative

Tags: ac-dc

I have this [AC to DC converter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/658) and I want to be able to split out the positive and negative wires from the barrel without cutting off the barrel.

I've been looking at options such as this [jack to terminal screw adapter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/368), but I don't think it is rated for 10amps (I want to use close to the full 10 amps).

What are my options? Does anyone know of something that can break out the barrel jack while sustaining the full amp level?

Comment: By default barrel jacks like that are designed for _no more_ than 5A. Looking at the 100+ cost, I am going to just guess loudly and proudly this isn't a specially constructed barrel, but a run-of-the-mill one. I.e. the one on the adaptor is probably also not rated for 10A. Whether you interpret that to mean you can buy another 5A rated one and use that, or that you need to think on whether this is the right adaptor for your cause, is up to you.

Comment: Thanks @Asmyldof, that was helpful. I guess my only option is to cut off the barrel then. Hopefully the actual wiring on the adaptor is designed to carry 10amps otherwise I will have some real issues....

Answer (score 1):

The problem with connectors like that is they have too much resistance and they heat up. I'd buy it and make sure it doesn't heat up under full load. If it does then find a different option.

Another option might be to find a jack and solder on wires, this was the only jack rated for 10A on [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-power-connectors/435?k=jack%202.1&k=&pkeyword=jack%202.1&pv2088=u10A&FV=ffe001b3&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=500).

You can also cut the wires and not use a jack, or cut the wires and solder on a terminal. Or cut the wires and use a terminal to terminal adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Cool.  I've never even seen an adapter like that!  I have been slicing with a razor blade on a DC charger cable to split off the positive and negative voltage.  Now I feel like an idiot!

If you do slice the cable (use like a box cutter / razor blade), you'll find the wires are quite thin.  I usually glob on a bunch of solder on each end, so I have some points where I can hook up alligator clips to each soldered glob end.

I would go on Digikey and look if you can something suitable for your current requirments.   They seem to be the source of all this stuff.

It can be a little hairy finding stuff like this on their site, but you just drill through the search results.

Forum post for some links to similiar adapters: https://forum.digikey.com/t/2-1-and-2-5-mm-barrel-plug-adapters/378

Adapter you mentioned (just so you can see what category Digikey puts it in):
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/adafruit-industries-llc/369/1528-1387-ND/5629435